# Forward slashes in http protocol declaration in URL

Tags: html, http, protocols

I have just noticed that on HTML form validation for an input type of url that the double forward slash '`//`' after the `protocol:` is not required. I tried entering URLs in to many browsers without the forward slashes and they all work e.g. http:www.web-dewd.com works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, and dare I say it, even IE11.

I cannot find any specific definition which states whether they are required or not. I spent a good few minutes on https://www.w3.org/standards/ without any luck. The best I could find was an interview with Tim Berners-Lee stating they are not required: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1220286/Sir-Tim-Berners-Lee-admits-forward-slashes-web-address-mistake.html :

> But with the colon in there as well, it turns out people never use the slash slash...

This [article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/double-slash-in-web-addresses-a-bit-of-a-mistake/) from ZDNet states:

> there is practically no reference to the double forward-slash on the web

**I would argue that slashes are recommended, but does anyone know and is able to provide evidence of what the correct standard is?**

*Somewhat ironically, Stackoverflow does require `//` when entering a link, as do other editors when determining to convert text to a link e.g. Microsoft Outlook.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt)

> *PrePrefix*: To be a Uniform Resource Locator as currently defined by the URI
>      working group, the whole string must start with a constant prefix
>      **"URL:"**

this part says that valid URL starts with `protocol:` and does not states anything about `//`

> *Internet protocol parts* Those schemes which refer to internet protocols mostly have a
>      **common syntax** for the rest of the object name. This **starts with a
>      double slash "//" to indicate its presence**, and continues until the
>      following slash "/".

---

To indicate URL string must start with `protocol:` and `//` is just common syntax to indicate domain name start.

When replacing URL usually you look for `http[s]://` instead of `http[s]:`. It's just common practice, and does not mean that all web developers will use that.

Comment: Good find. From here, right? https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.html I googled one of your quotes.

Comment: Er ... how about using [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)? You know, the *current* spec?